# Activity leaked :android.view.WindowLeakedActivity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window DecorView@bf6bd49[]

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-alertdialog

This is my MainScreenActivity.java code:

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity{

Button btnViewProducts;
Button btnNewProduct;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    // Buttons
    btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
    btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // view products click event
    btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Launching All products Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    // view products click event
    btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching create new product activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

My AllProductsActivity.java:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect2/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Below is my logcat:

```
11-25 13:59:59.941 10468-10468/com.example.androidhive E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window DecorView@bf6bd49[] that was originally added here
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:417)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
                                                                        at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:613)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:560)
                                                                        at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I'm just a beginner and I have no idea what is causing the error. I have searched the site for solutions but it seems that this error is code specific. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check if pDialog.dismiss(); gets really called

Comment: I think some problem happend before pDialog.dismiss(); and you don't required runOnUI inside onPostExecute because onPostExecute already doing task in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in do in background, check your else condition you are starting another activity from there so just put pDialog.dismiss(); before you start another activity

Reason behind this crash is you dialog is still showing and you are changing Activity so its showing WindowLeaked error

As you doInBackground will not allow to hide dialog you can hide it in onPause() method it will also work

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you have not initialize your ProgressDialog properly or you do not close your progress dialog properly. Make sure that in `onPause()` you call  `pDialog.dismiss();` And also initialize in this way.

Make object of `Context` and initialize it in `onCreate();` as `mContext=YourActivity.this`

```
 pDialog= ProgressDialog.show(mContext);
```